# Menu moves left on hover

Tags: html, css, menu

When I hover over one of my menu items, the menu moves to the left. Why is that?

**HTML:**

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="geschiedenis.html">Geschiedenis</a></li>
        <li><a href="team.html">Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="agenda.html">Agenda</a>
        <li><a href="fotos.html">Foto's</a></li>
        <li><a href="vacatures.html">Vacatures</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
nav {
  float: right;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 55px;
}
nav li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 25px;
  position: relative;
}
nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: gray;
  font-size: 20px;
}
nav li:hover a {
  color: black;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i can see you need to increase the size of the menu link when use hover on it but if you increase `font-size` this will dislocate the position of the link and thats the reason you link was moving to left.

Use css `transform:scale(1.1,1.1)` property to increase the size without change in position.

```css
nav {
  float: right;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 55px;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-right: 25px;
  position: relative;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: gray;
  display:block;
}

nav li:hover a {
  color: black;
  transform:scale(1.1,1.1);
  -moz-transform:scale(1.1,1.1);
  -ms-transform:scale(1.1,1.1);
  -o-transform:scale(1.1,1.1);
  -webkit-transform:scale(1.1,1.1);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="geschiedenis.html">Geschiedenis</a></li>
    <li><a href="team.html">Team</a></li>
    <li><a href="agenda.html">Agenda</a>
    <li><a href="fotos.html">Foto's</a></li>
    <li><a href="vacatures.html">Vacatures</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

> transform property should be use with prefix to let it support in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove `nav li:hover a { font-size:22px; }` so that it does not move left on hover

Comment: Is there an option to not remove it, and make the text stay at it's regular position?

Comment: Provide the same font size:22px  to  nav a { font-size:22px; }

Answer (score 0):

Replace `float` with `inline-block` for `<li>`. And you are changing `font-size` on hover which is creating dancing effect on list items. Better keep same `font-size` for normal and hover states.

```css
nav {
  float: right;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 55px;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-right: 25px;
  position: relative;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: gray;
}

nav li:hover a {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="geschiedenis.html">Geschiedenis</a></li>
    <li><a href="team.html">Team</a></li>
    <li><a href="agenda.html">Agenda</a>
    <li><a href="fotos.html">Foto's</a></li>
    <li><a href="vacatures.html">Vacatures</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: If changing font-size is very necessary there is one possibility, you can change it for your active list item. I mean on hover `font-size` will not change but only active item will have larger `font-size`.

Answer (score 0):

Try playing with flex in css3 to see if that works for growing the text. Also there is an HTML menu tag you may want to have a look at.